# jQuery How to get td cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of invoice number when user clicks anywhere on a row

Below is my table

```
<div class="panel ui-widget-content" id="invoiceList">
<h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="cursor: pointer; "><span>Invoices</span></h2>
    <table cellspacing='0' id='header' class="ui-widget">
        <tr>
            <th>Invoice Number</th>
             <th>Invoice Total</th>
        </tr>     
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"  >INV-Error_Test1</a></td>
            <td>22.000000 USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"  >INV-Error_Test2</a></td>
           <td>22.000000 USD</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

Below is the jQuery I have which gives the Invoice Number only if its clicked on `Invoice Number` field

```
$("#invoiceList td").click(function (e) {
var result = $(this).text();
console.log('invoice --->'+result);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5n62md3m/

Can someone help me get the invoice number when user clicks anywhere on the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative solution could be

```
$('#invoiceList tr:not(:first-child)').click(function(e){
   $tds = $(this).find("td");
   console.log( $tds.eq(0).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this, it could be a solution:

```js
$('tbody tr').on('click', function(e){
   var value = $(this).find('td:first-child a').text();
  alert(value);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel ui-widget-content" id="invoiceList">
<h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="cursor: pointer; "><span>Invoices</span></h2>
    <table cellspacing='0' id='header' class="ui-widget">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Invoice Number</th>
             <th>Invoice Total</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"  >INV-Error_Test1</a></td>
            <td>22.000000 USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"  >INV-Error_Test2</a></td>
           <td>22.000000 USD</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: The last child is the total. The invoice number is the first child.

Comment: Thanks i missed that he wants the invoice number

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#invoiceList tr:not(:first-child)").click(function (e) {
    console.log('invoice ---> '+$(this).children('td:nth-child(1) a').text());
}
```

A small bonus here that if you want to get another column, you can only change the number in `nth-child` (and remove the trailing `a`, possibly).